# Copy Constructor is not called but default constructor is called java

Tags: java, constructor, copy, clone

```
package primary;

public class Room implements Cloneable{

    int room_no;
    private int leftStrength; //number of students sitting on left side
    private int rightStrength;//number of students sitting on right side
    private int capacity;
    private int timeSlot;
    private boolean checkBig;
     boolean invigilanceRequired;
    private int rightCapacity;
    private int leftCapacity;
    public Room(int room_no,int capacity)
    {
        this.room_no=room_no;
        this.capacity=capacity;
        rightStrength=0;
        leftStrength=0;
        timeSlot=0;
        checkBig=true;
        invigilanceRequired=true;
        rightCapacity=capacity;
        leftCapacity=capacity;
    }

    public Room(Room other)
    {
        this.room_no=other.room_no;
        this.capacity=other.capacity;
        this.rightStrength=other.rightStrength;
        this.leftStrength=other.leftStrength;
        this.timeSlot=other.timeSlot;
        this.checkBig=other.checkBig;
        this.invigilanceRequired=other.invigilanceRequired;
        this.rightCapacity=other.rightCapacity;
        this.leftCapacity=other.leftCapacity;
    }
    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.clone();
    }

}
```

I have tried copy constructor and clone() to make a copy of Room object but everytime it gives same object and doesn't copy. I found that it always calls parametrized constructor.
A small part of code where I am calling Room copy constructors:

```
public TimeInterval(TimeInterval other) throws CloneNotSupportedException 
    {
        course_to_room=new ArrayList<>();
        map=new HashMap<>();
        rooms=new ArrayList<>();
        this.day_no=other.day_no;
        this.time_interval=other.time_interval;
        for(Course course:other.course_to_room)
        {
            this.course_to_room.add((Course)course.clone());
        }

        for(Room room:other.rooms)
        {
            Room tempRoom=new Room(room);
            this.rooms.add(tempRoom);
        }


        for(Integer key:other.map.keySet())
        {
            ArrayList<Course> temp=other.map.get(key);
            ArrayList<Course> newClone=new ArrayList<>();
            for(Course course:temp)
            {
                newClone.add(new Course(course));
            }


            this.map.put(key, newClone);
        }
    }
```

Here , I am doing exact code to copy Room object:

```
TimeInterval save1=new TimeInterval(time1);
```

when i print any variable from above 2 objects, save1 and time1, they are different.

I am adding input commands and output

```
System.out.println("Old time 1,Room 5 capacity left                           "+save1.R4.getRightCapacity());
System.out.println("Old time 2,Room 5 capacity left "+save2.R4.getRightCapacity());
System.out.println("Old time 2,Room 5 right strength "+save2.R4.getRightStrength());
System.out.println("Old time 1,Room 5 capacity left "+time1.R4.getRightCapacity());
System.out.println("Old time 2,Room 5 capacity left "+time2.R4.getRightCapacity());
System.out.println("Old time 2,Room 5 time 1 right strength "+time1.R4.getRightStrength());
```

OUTPUT:

Old time 1,Room 5 capacity left 60

Old time 2,Room 5 capacity left 60

Old time 2,Room 5 right strength 0

Old time 1,Room 5 capacity left 0

Old time 2,Room 5 capacity left 60

Old time 2,Room 5 time 1 right strength 60

Comment: Could you be clearer about what the problem is, and how you've concluded there's a problem?

Comment: I have printed rightStrength variable from save1 and time1. save1 is showing 0. time1 is showing 60. It's in loop so time1 has changed over time and save1 should copy this changed value to rightStrength. But rightStrength is still 0. So, I concluded that it's calling parametrized constructor.

Comment: If there's a `rightStrength` variable on `TimeInterval`, you haven't shown it. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: rightStrength variable is in Room class.

Comment: Do you mean you change `rightStrength` on `time1` to 60 _after_ or _before_ you create `save1`?

Comment: But we don't know the relationship between `Room` and `TimeInterval`. We can't offer much help without all the relevant code.

Comment: Yes we do.  `TimeInterval` clearly has a field of type `List<Room>`.

Comment: Incidentally, the best way to see exactly what's being called is to step through this with your debugger.

Comment: public class TimeInterval implements Cloneable {

 int day_no;
  int time_interval;
  ArrayList<Course> course_to_room;
  Map<Integer,ArrayList<Course>> map;
  
  ArrayList<Room> rooms;
  
  
 public TimeInterval(int day_no,int time_interval)
 {
  this.day_no=day_no;
  this.time_interval=time_interval;
  course_to_room=new ArrayList<>();
  map=new HashMap<>();
  rooms=new ArrayList<>();
  addRooms();
 }

Comment: Adding code to comments won't format properly, try editing your question. (It will help if you also provide the print-statements you use together with the results you get and the results you expect. Being precise helps on StackOverflow.)

Comment: I changed time1 to 60 after creating save1 but it's in for loop. First time,it's printing the same value for rightStrength but second time, it's still printing the same value of rightStrength what was before but updated value is getting printed in case of time1.

Comment: I have added input commands and output

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with default constructors.

Comment: It's still impossible to follow what your actual question is, when you've got `time1`, `time2`, `save1`, `save2` in one snippet of code, but you don't ever show how two of them are getting created; and you haven't clearly stated what you expect to see where.  Please try to ask the question more clearly, if you haven't solved this yourself yet, and supply something reproducible that all of us can run.  Seriously though, I stand by my earlier advice that you should step through this with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this question. I printed something in all the constructors and debugged line by line. I found that this statement( TimeInterval save1=new TimeInterval(time1); ) caused the issue.
I write what i found in steps:

1. When TimeInterval save1=new TimeInterval(time1); started executing, it called parametrised constructor(which I called default by mistake) of the Room. Then it called copy constructor of the Room.
2. But I expected it to just call copy constructor of the Room. Then, I found that I made some Room objects (not just reference, but entire object by calling 'new' keyword)outside the copy constructor of the TimeInterval class.
3. I put these these lines where I was making Room objects in the parametrized constructor of the TimeInterval class.
4. Problem got resolved.
5. Issue for printing wrong values: When TimeInterval class made Room objects using parametrized constructor ( for those lines written outside the constructors in TimeInterval class), it initialized  those variables which I printed in Room objects to default values( which was 0 ). Then, it called copy constructor of the Room and just made copy of these Room objects( whose variables have default values), NOT the copy of those room objects which I intended.

Answer (score -1):

Java doesn't have copy constructors in the same way that C++ does.

You have made two constructors, one takes a room number and capacity, the other makes one from an existing room. You do not have a default constructor. Also, there is no automatic use of 'copy constructor' in Java. Instead, if you want to make a copy then you explicitly would do so by explicitly calling the Room(Room) constructor you made.

Is the issue that you are wanting to get the 'clone' method to call the Room(Room) constructor? In that case you could call it from inside the 'clone' method if that is what is needed.

When you say they are different, how do you mean? Are you printing the addresses and noting they are different physical objects? or are you saying the parameters that should be identical are not?

Comment: i have explicitly called Room copy constructor. I have already mentioned that code.

Comment: for(Room room:other.rooms)
        {
            Room tempRoom=new Room(room);
            this.rooms.add(tempRoom);
        }

Comment: Variables have different values in these 2 objects

Comment: You might want to reword the title on your question. Your problem seems to have to do with the copies having their fields updated or not? I still am not 100% understanding what your issue is, but I sense that somewhere in your code you are updating the rightStrength value but it is not being updated in the way you would want?

Comment: yes, it's updating as I want. But when I make a copy of time1 and save it to save1. time1 displays correct updated value. But save1 shows the value which I entered in default(parametrized) constructor

Comment: @Ashwani Tanwar, you don't have any default constructors in the classes you showed us.

Comment: Given the code that you show, it would be one thing if we thought that somehow a default constr was being called. But given that the indication is that the (int, int) constr is being called in place of the copy constr (with the original parameters no less) that would imply that somehow you are calling the (int, int) version in your code. So there are two options. Either show the code where you are calling that, or else put print statements in all the constructors, that way you will see exactly when each is called. This eliminates guessing

Comment: If it's not clear what OP is asking (and really, it's not clear at all), then requests for clarification belong in comments under the question, not in an "answer" .  I don't consider this an answer at all - you've really just asked OP what's going on.  And your initial statement about Java not having copy constructors - not really true.  The constructors that OP has shown are definitely copy constructors.  The mystery to all of us is what else is lurking in OP's code.

Comment: @David thank you for the feedback, I'm still new to Stack Overflow and just learning my way around. It's true that I was asking for more info in order to help solve the problem he was seeing. But the system does not seem to allow me to post to the comments area in the OP. It indicates that I would need to have a 50 point standing to be able to do so (that's why I clicked on answer, and posted in this area instead). For now I'll just provide answers where no additional info is required

Comment: Cool, sorry if I came across as overly harsh.  I should have realised you were a fairly new user, before I started criticising what you did.  I apologise for that.  You'll find that most things on Stack Overflow get easier to manage as you accumulate reputation.  So good luck and welcome.